# Data from a solid data pod but it always comes back as undefined. How do i retrieve data from a inrupt solid data pod correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sparql, solid

I am trying to retrieve the organization-name, or any data from the following endpoint.

https://isumotest.inrupt.net/profile/card#me

However whenever i try to grab anything it always comes back as undefined

```
const $rdf = require('rdflib')
const store  = $rdf.graph();

const me = store.sym('https://isumotest.inrupt.net/profile/card#me');
const profile = me.doc();       //i.e. store.sym(''https://example.com/alice/card#me')

const VCARD = new $rdf.Namespace('http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#');
const FOAF = new $rdf.Namespace('http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/');

let name = store.any(me, VCARD('organization-name'));
console.log(name);
console.log('Request Ended');
```

For example:

```
$ node app.js
undefined
Request Ended
```

Any help is very much appreciated, i have been stuck on this for quite a while.

Comment: if I'm not totally wrong here, you have to load the data into the store . `store.sym` just returns the node identified by the URI. You should walk through the tutorial again: https://github.com/solid/solid-tutorial-rdflib.js - especially the section with loading data into the store is important for you I'd say.

Comment: define `var fetcher = new $rdf.Fetcher(store, timeout)` and then do `fetcher.nowOrWhenFetched('https://isumotest.inrupt.net/profile/card#me', function(ok, body, xhr) {
    if (!ok) {
        console.log("Oops, something happened and couldn't fetch data");
    } else {
        const me = store.sym('https://isumotest.inrupt.net/profile/card#me');
        let name = store.any(me, VCARD('organization-name'));
        console.log(name);
    }
})`

Comment: @AKSW That totally did what i needed thank you for helping out my simple doc confusion. You should probably post it as a answer to this question and get your free internet points :)